# How to recognize unknown faces in face recognition using emguCV c#?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, face-recognition

**I'm working on a face recognition system using emguCV 4.0.1 where I'm facing issue in detecting unknown faces. The issue is system always returns nearest matching face from the database for the unknown face.**

I have used a combination of three algorithms(EIGEN, FISHER & LBPH) to get better accuracy in face recognition. It gives 80-90% accuracy for the faces which are already present in the database, but for the unknown face which not present in the database, it always returns the best match face from the database.

```
EigenFaceRecognizer eigenFaceRecognizer = new EigenFaceRecognizer(4,5000);
FisherFaceRecognizer FisheigenFaceRecognizer = new FisherFaceRecognizer(4, 5000);  
LBPHFaceRecognizer LBPeigenFaceRecognizer = new LBPHFaceRecognizer(4, 8, 8, 8, 5000)

var result = eigenFaceRecognizer.Predict(_grayFrame);
var resultFish = FisheigenFaceRecognizer.Predict(_grayFrame);
var LBPresult = LBPeigenFaceRecognizer.Predict(_grayFrame);

if (result.Label != -1 && resultFish.Label != -1 && LBPresult.Label != -1)
{
    if ( result.Label == resultFish.Label == LBPresult.Label)
    {
     return Label;
    }
}
else
{
return "Unknown"
}
```

Comment: Do you get the match % on the face returned?  Can you check that as part of your _if_?  If it's not in your threshold then you can kick out and return the value you want.

Comment: @StinkyTowel
I'm not getting any match % in c#.
I'm getting Label & Distance value in return from Predict()

Comment: I believe you could set a desired threshold against the distance, but it's arbitrary and may depend on how 'trained' your model is.  Here are some [examples](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Emgu.CV/EigenFaceRecognizer/Predict/php-eigenfacerecognizer-predict-method-examples.html) that may provide some insight.

Comment: @StinkyTowel
What is the correct value for the threshold? right now I'm using 5000 as a threshold.
Then what will be the criteria(distance value) for the unknown person?

Comment: There's no easy answer, at least in my limited knowledge with AI and ML.  It can be "subjective" and may require more training of your model and/or tweaking the threshold and retraining.

Comment: @StinkyTowel
can you tell me how many images i should train per person for better accuracy?
Right now im training 200 above images per person.
Total training images= number of person * 200

Comment: The answer may be 'it depends' b/c there are many variables/parameters.  Check this [article](https://medium.com/@williamkoehrsen/facial-recognition-using-googles-convolutional-neural-network-5aa752b4240e) which may provide some insight on the challenge.  It could also be the implementation of the algorithm you're using that does not allow for configuring a pass/fail threshold.  Have you checked out the latest ML.Net offerings?  There may be some better abstracted options to get you where you want to go.